# OleDbCommand can't excute this command, Why?

Tags: ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I create a table named "PathTable" in a MS-Access DB.
The table is like this:

```
------------------------------
| IP        | Input | Output |
------------------------------
| 127.0.0.1 | XXXXX | YYYYYY |
------------------------------
```

When I programed these

```
String CommandString = "SELECT Input, Output FROM PathTable WHERE IP = '127.0.0.1'";

OleDbCommand CommandObj = new OleDbCommand( CommandString, m_Connection );

OleDbDataReader ReaderObj = CommandObj.ExecuteReader();
```

the code always throw OleDbException, and the ErrorDescription is E_FAIL(0x80004005),

But if I replaced the commandString with

```
SELECT * FROM PathTable WHERE IP = '127.0.0.1'
```

The problem never happended again.

So, my question is: Does OleDbCommand only excute "select * "? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe these are [reserved](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) words. Try quoting them:

```
SELECT [Input], [Output] FROM PathTable WHERE IP = '127.0.0.1'
```

Comment: Won't that treat them as string literals Darin?

Comment: Thank you, Darin. "Input" and "Output" are MS-Access reserved words indeed.But I've never known.

Comment: Is it not true that an alternative to the brackets (which are evil and will break the standard Access SQL 89 implementation of derived tables) is to fully qualify the fields, i.e., "SELECT PathTable.Input, PathTable.Output"?

Comment: @David W. Fenton: Access's ANSI-89 Query Mode's implementation of derived tables is itself evil. Note that "SQL-89" refers to a SQL Standard' and that the Access parlance is ANSI-89. Also note that Standard SQL uses double quotes (ascii code 0034) rather than square brackets to escape keywords so alluding to SQL Standards here is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I am sending you the list of Microsoft reserved words, Please check, you are using reserved keyword that's why you are facing this problem.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266

Answer (score 0):

It's possible 'input' or 'output' are reserved words in Access SQL so try adding [] square brackets around those field names.

Comment: Not only Access SQL but ODBC and ISO/ANSI Standard SQL from SQL-92 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Input and Output may be keywords. Try surrounding them with square brackets. i.e.

[Input]
[Output]

Answer (score 0):

File Not Found - Another possible cause of this exception is if the File your trying to load/read does not exist.

I have found it useful to perform a "File.Exists" before trying to open the file just to make sure my code detects this specific cause of the "IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)" exception correctly.